# Wine Application doesn't register mouse input

Tags: wine, mouse

I recently installed GameMaker Studio 2 with Wine64, and it went pretty smoothly. Except when I opened up the application I could not use my mouse within GMS2. Buttons didn't light up when I hovered over them and clicking doesn't do anything. I can type though, when the login popup appeared I could type my Email address and try to log in with the enter key. I've tried to look up my problem, but I couldn't find anyone who had my specific issue so I have no idea what I'm supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been 5 months by now, but just in case you haven't managed to solve it yet: I've wrestled with this problem for the past week or so and I did a bunch of things that might or might not have helped, but what ultimately solved the issue was to **use winecfg to change the Windows version to Windows 7.**